# cpp division - how to get most accurate outcome?

Tags: c++, division

I want to divide two ull variables and get the most accurate outcome.
what is the best way to do that?

i.e.  5000034 / 5000000  = 1.0000068

Comment: Cast one of the operands to `double` and then divide?

Comment: ull = unsigned long long

Comment: I'm writing a timer and i want to see if (myMeasuredTime / realTime) is bigger than some number. the problem is, that myMeasuredTime and realTime are both ull.

Comment: Do you mean unsigned long long?  As Jon says, if you cast one number to `double` the calculation will be performed in double-precision, which is precise enough for most purposes.  The precision of your machine's timings might not be good enough, though, depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want "most accurate precision" - you should avoid floating point arithmetics.

You might want to use some big decimal library [whcih usually implements [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29) arithmetic], and will allow you to define the precision you are seeking.

You should avoid floating point arithmetic because thet are not exact [you have finite number of bits to represent infinite number of numbers in every range, so some slicing must occure...]. Fixed point arithmetic [as usually implemented in big decimal libraries] allows you to allocate more bits "on the fly" to represent the number in the desired accuracy.

More info on the floating point issue can be found in this [a bit advanced] article: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: The reference is good, but "most accurate precision" doesn't mean anything, and machine `double` is usually the best choice for accuracy.

Comment: @JamesKanze: "most accurate precision" is what the OP is is asking for, of course it doesn't mean anything, what is the "most accurate precision" for `e` or `pi`? I only meant that using a fixed point arithmetic - unlike what you get with double precision - you can **control** the precision you get, unlike with floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (double)(N) / D, do 1 + ( (double)(N - D) / D)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that “the most accurate outcome” doesn't mean 
much.  No finite representation can represent all real numbers exactly;
how precise the representation can be depends on the size of the type
and its internal representation.  On most implementations, `double` will
give about 17 decimal digits precision, which is usually several orders
more precise than the input; for a single multiplicatio or division,
`double` is usually fine.  (Problems occur with addition and subtraction
when the difference between the two values is extreme.)  There exist
packages which offer larger precision (`BigDecimal`, `BigFloat` and the
like), but they are never exact: in the end, the precision is limited by
the amount of memory you're willing to let them use.  They're also much
slower than `double`, and generally (slightly) more difficult to use
correctly (since they have more options, e.g. just how much precision do
you want).  The only real answer to your question is another question:
how much precision do you need?  And for what sequence of operations?
Rounding errors accumulate, so while `double` may be largely sufficient
for a single division, it may cause problems if used naïvely for
iterative procedures.  Although in such cases, the solution isn't
usually to increase the precision, but to change the algorithm in a way
to avoid the problems.  If `double` gives you the precision you need,
use it in preference to any extended type.  If it doesn't, and you don't
have a choice, then choose one of the existing arbitrary precision
libraries, such as GMP.

(You might also have an issue with the way rounding is handled.  For
bookkeeping purposes, for example, most jurisdictions have very strict
laws concerning how to round monitary values, and their rules are based
on decimal arithmetic.  In such cases, you'll need a numeric type which
does decimal arithmetic in order for the rounding to conform in all
cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are probably most accurate for multiplication and division, while integers and fixed point numbers are the best choice for addition and subtraction. This follows from the fact that multiplication and division changes the order of magnitude which floating point numbers handle better, while addition and subtraction is some kind of step, which integers and fixed point numbers handle better.

If you want the best accuracy when dividing integers, implement a RationalNumber class containing the numerator and denominator. This way your reslut will always be exact if you avoid arithmetic overflow. This requires that you accept output in fractional form.